# Why can $\frac{{{x^2}}}{{\sqrt y }} \le t$ be prepresent as the the following equivalent second order cone constraint?

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, change-of-variable, second-order-cone-programming

I am quite new to the field of convex optimization and in a research paper that I have read, some author represent this constraint $\frac{{{x^2}}}{{\sqrt y }} \le t$ as equivalent SOC constraint like this without explanation

[image]

Could you kindly explain to me why this is possible and how can they come up with an excellent use of the auxiliary variable $v$ to turn the original constrain into SOC form ?

Thank you for your enthusiasm !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you can use SOC to write a constraint $$pq\geq r^2,$$ namely as $$\|2r,p-q\|_2\leq p+q,$$
and that makes it possible to write various simple inequalities between monomials, and then put them together to get more complicated monomials.

Since you want to model $t\sqrt{y}\geq x^2$ it feels natural to start with $$tv\geq x^2$$ and to complete the model you are forced to take $$\sqrt{y}\geq v,$$ which is also fine because it is equivalent to the same type of SOC: $$1\cdot y\geq v^2.$$

These are rather well-known tricks you can read about in  https://docs.mosek.com/modeling-cookbook/cqo.html#simple-sets-involving-power-functions.

PS. The second inequality from your post looks wrong, $v$ and $y$ should be switched.

Comment: Can we just go directly
$t\sqrt y  \ge {x^2} \Leftrightarrow {\left\| {2x,t - \sqrt y } \right\|_2} \le t + \sqrt y $ without introducing the extra variable $v$ ??

Comment: @TuongNguyenMinh It is correct mathematically, but it is not a SOC representation because the expressions involving $\sqrt{y}$ are not linear.

Comment: Oh thank you, about the auxiliary variable $v$ shouldn't it be like this.
Let $v \ge \sqrt y$, we have $v \ge \sqrt y  \Rightarrow tv \ge t\sqrt y$ also

$\left\{ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
{tv \ge t\sqrt y }\\
{t\sqrt y  \ge {x^2}}
\end{array}} \right.$

Therefore $tv \ge {x^2}$ instead of $\sqrt y  \ge v$

Comment: @TuongNguyenMinh From $y\geq v^2$ and $tv\geq x^2$ you can deduce $t\sqrt{y}\geq x^2$ and all is good. In what you propose you get some inequalities the wrong way around.

Comment: From my viewpoint if $\sqrt y  \ge v$ we would come to this point

$\left\{ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
{t\sqrt y  \ge tv}\\
{t\sqrt y  \ge {x^2}}
\end{array}} \right.$

THis is not sufficent to conclude that 

$tv \ge {x^2}$

Comment: @TuongNguyenMinh You are making a fairly common mistake. The point is not to conclude $tv\geq x^2$. The point is to conclude $t\sqrt{y}\geq x^2$ (since that is what you want to get in the end) from the inequalities you have in the model ($\sqrt{y}\geq v$ and $tv\geq x^2$). You obtain those inequalities by guessing, which I tried to explain in the answer.

Comment: Oh thank you so much ! So that is how it was all about !. This is where I was wrong "The point is not to conclude tv≥x2. The point is to conclude ty√≥x2"